# Failed review audit on an answer to a question about a specification

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed [a review audit on late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/7928016).

[image: Failed audit]

Here is [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172166/is-there-an-implementation-specification-for-the-kermit-file-transfer-protocol).

I chose “No action needed” since, in my opinion, the answer did provide exactly what the question asked. Even though a book is requested in the original question, to me it doesn't seem to attract opinionated answers. A specification either exists or doesn't, and if it does, it is either correct or incorrect. If the book in question didn't contain a correct one, the answer wouldn't be particularly good, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

The answer isn't even link-only as suggested in the comment, since it provides the name of the book, its author and an ISBN number. The alternative, posting the full specification to Stack Overflow, wouldn't be feasible.

More to the point, if the question were indeed off-topic, the answer still isn't a good candidate for a review audit, since in that case the question should be reviewed.

There probably aren't many cases in which specifications are requested, but how should they be treated?

Comment: This kind of answer just causes reviewers to immediately press the Red Button without thinking about it.  So it got deleted, something you could have easily found out yourself and pass the audit.

Comment: I think you did not read the question.The answer does not match with the question.The comment on the answer comes from another review(very low quality) means someone voted it for deletion and I see its deleted.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes. Instead I decided to think myself.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Which part of the question? The way I read it, the OP concludes that an implementation specification would be preferable to what they had found so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that's not a great audit; I've removed it from consideration.

My one criticism is that you failed by choosing "no action needed"; as much as the answer *does* answer the question, I disagree that it needed no action at all. You could've edited it (as I did) to offer readers a quick link to purchase the book in question ($4, what a steal!) or, if you truly felt it was adequate as-is, you could've upvoted it as a signal to future readers (who would otherwise see the negative score and perhaps wonder what unspoken horrors lay in wait for them between the pages of the referenced tome).

Comment: Why hasn't the question been closed for requesting an offsite resource?